# Is there a p-adic triangle geometry?

Tags: triangles, p-adic-number-theory, plane-geometry

While understanding an analytic construction of $p$-adic numbers is relatively easy (as are understanding Hensel decomposition and basic operations — addition, multiplication…), the field seems to get incredibly hard if we want to go further.

I was looking for what a $p$-adic geometry would look like, hoping for a new playfield, but all I could find are papers from P. Scholze which are way beyond my level (and my motivation).

Is there a nice and gentle $p$-adic geometry, like for instance a $p$-adic triangle geometry ?

Googling these terms lead me to a presentation of B. Le Stum stating that all triangles are isosceles in $\mathbb{Q}_p$, which is true but seems to me as relevant as saying that all triangles verify « the length of the longest side is the sum of the lengths of the other two's » in $\mathbb{R}$. I was rather looking for a triangle geometry in $\mathbb{Q}_p^2$ or maybe $\mathbb{C}_p$.

Does this question even make sense ? Or is there no such thing, at least none that would be relevant* ?

(*For instance, though it is totally possible to define an order over $\mathbb{C}$, there is no interest in doing so, as no order will ever respect the structure of $\mathbb{C}$ — and we should definitively think of $\mathbb{C}$ as a set with no order.

Maybe, likewise it is possible to define a metric over $\mathbb{Q}_p^2$, but none that would have any interest ?)

Comment: I’m sure you’ve seen that if $A$, $B$, and $C$ are three distinct $p$-adic numbers, then two of the distances are equal. As people say, every $p$-adic triangle is isosceles. There’s no concept of “between-ness” that makes sense $p$-adically, either. I recommend thinking of the $p$-adic situation in its own terms, not as having any properties copyable from the familiar situation..

Comment: @Lubin : Thank you sir for your answer. I certainly know little about p-adic numbers, but I believe (at least hope) I understood how p-adic numbers are different : ultrametrics, non-archimedean, $\bar{\mathbb{Q}_p}$ of infinite degree, and so on. I see you have worked with J. Tate so I guess if there were anything relevant you would know about it.
If I consider three elements of $\mathbb{C}_p$ (which is sometimes called _Tate field_, apparently), does the «isoscele rule» still stands ? I do not know where to find how to manipulate elements of $\mathbb{C}_p$, or even how we can decompose them.

Comment: The "isosceles rule" holds true in every ultrametric space, as it follows directly from the strong triangle inequality. All finite-dimensional (and many infinite-dimensional) vector spaces over $\mathbb Q_p$ or $\mathbb C_p$ (and many others) are such ultrametric spaces in a natural way. What sources have you looked at? I always recommend Schikhof's *Ultrametric Calculus*.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg : thanks for your answer. As often with me, I was learning using Wikipedia, also a lecture from P. Colmez on youtube (and lecture papers from him).

I looked at _Ultrametric Calculus_'s [content](https://assets.cambridge.org/97805210/32872/toc/9780521032872_toc.pdf) and it is interesting. Sadly bit of expensive for a hobby, but I'll consider it ! Thanks again.